# How To add multiple Countdown timer query in a same html page?

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

I want to create a online auction site. I need to mention every auction ending time & date.

For this I have created a `countdown.js` file like this:

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2014").getTime();
// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {
    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + " D : " + hours + " H : " + minutes + " M : " + seconds + " S";
}, 1000);
```

And I have imported this in my html as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/countdown.js"></script>
 <p style="font-size:larger;color:Red;font-weight:bolder">END IN</p>
                    <h5><i id="countdown"></i></h5><br />
```

It's working fine. Now I want to add one or more timer in the same page. While I use this code

```
<h5><i id="countdown"></i></h5><br />
```

It's showing an error in ID. How to rectify this?

Comment: Did you try searching for one before trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Does each one your <i> tags have an id="countdown".  You should use a class if so.  You only want 1 element referencing an id.  That will also result in a change your javascript -> getElementsByClass which isn't support in ie8 and below.

Comment: Either use class, or make that junk of javascript a function with a parameter where the parameter is the id of an <i> tag. You need different ids for different <i> tags. Remember to call the function with the appropriate argument (tag id) when document is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your code into one function which is accepting 2 params elementId and target date

```
  function setTimer(elem_id, date) {
 // set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date(date).getTime();
// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
// get tag element

var countDownElem = document.getElementById(elem_id);
//update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {
   // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
  // do some time calculations
  days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
  hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
  minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
  seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
  // format countdown string + set tag value
  countDownElem.innerHTML = days + " D : " + hours + " H : " + minutes + " M : " + seconds + " S";
}, 1000);
}
setTimer("countdown1","Aug 15, 2014");
setTimer("countdown2","Aug 17, 2014");
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aZAw/2/) for above code

Comment: But I need different countdown timer in the same page..?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, but I noticed the second timer is showing to be an hour longer away than the first timer.